# If i buy a Ubisoft game on Steam will it appear in UPLAY list as well?

Tags: steam, assassins-creed, ubisoft-connect

I want to buy on sale a Ubisoft game on Steam. The only problem is that i want to collect all Ubisoft games on UPLAY. If i buy the game on Steam will it appear in the UPLAY games list? so i will be able to just launch UPLAY instead of Steam to play the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many (if not all) Ubisoft games on Steam actually are activated and launched through Uplay. This should be easy to find by viewing the store page and looking by the publisher info and game genres + peripheral and gameplay style tags. For example on the [AC: Odyssey](https://store.steampowered.com/app/812140/Assassins_Creed_Odyssey/) page it says:

> Requires 3rd-Party Account: Ubisoft Account (Supports Linking to Steam Account)

You can also check [PCGamingWiki](https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Assassin%27s_Creed_Odyssey)'s "Availability" table -- notice for AC: Odyssey it says that it's available on Steam but uses Uplay as DRM.

Answer (score 1):

This is my complete experience with Steam and UPlay.

Mini description:

- Ubisoft games bought on Steam are unlocked on UPlay as well but the game files and DLC are downloaded/bought on Steam.
- Achivements are unlocked on UPlay, if you remove the game from Steam
  they will remain on UPlay but you wont be able to install the game.

I have bought on sale Assassin's Creed Unity, i installed it through Steam, i have press the "Play" button and a popup appeared asking me to link the Steam account to Uplay. After i have connected them AC Unity appeared on my Uplay account games list.

I have uninstalled AC Unity from Steam and i have tried to install it via UPlay but i couldnt't do that, Steam launched. I couldn't buy any DLC via UPlay, even though the game appears in UPlay it is still a Steam game. The achievements are on UPlay but the game files and DLC are through Steam.

Than i have asked for a refund, the game disappeared from Steam but i still have the unlocked achievements on UPlay.

Comment: I Agree with your answer, just one thing, at least AC I cant be unlocked in uplay if you buy it in Steam, saying that by my experience.